# Cannot create application with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Rails. While creating a new application with the command:

```
rails new myapp
```

The following error messages occur:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake (10.1.0) 
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/build_info/rake-10.1.0.info
An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The version of my gem is 4.0.0.

Comment: can you run `gem install rake -v '10.1.0' --trace` and post the output here?

Comment: Where are you trying to install? Seems like a `sudo` issue ...

Comment: Yep, I'll have to agree with @Guy. This seem to be a permission problem. Are you using Ruby that come preinstalled with your system? If so, `sudo` may be resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be permission problem so change the permission of the directory and then try:

```
gem install rake -v '10.1.0'
```

and post the logs if an error happens.

Or try:

```
sudo gem install rake -v '10.1.0'
```

and then post the logs if there is an error again.

Answer (score 1):

This is unlikely to be a rake issue, since rake uses the generic gem install mechanism. My guess is that you have permissions screwed up in the gem install directory.

You can do:

```
gem env gemdir
```

to see where gems are being installed. Check the permissions in that area to make sure everything is writeable by you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid `sudo` to make bundler install the gems into your `~/.gem/ruby/2.0.0` directory, try setting the `$GEM_HOME` environment variable:

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bundler issue with the recent versions of rubygems.  See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2445 for details.